az account list return different result with Web console
I install Azure CLI inside Ubuntu WSL 2 (Windows 10).
root@LT142:~# az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.63.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.63.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.1.0",
  "extensions": {
    "account": "0.2.5"
  }
}
root@LT142:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy


root@LT142:~# az account list
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "8e1e397d-74c6-4f72-9735-7583dd199d48",
    "id": "cb1c2d2d-685c-4da7-a032-e50920819397",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "vy-august2024",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantDefaultDomain": "donhuvyhotmail.onmicrosoft.com",
    "tenantDisplayName": "Default Directory",
    "tenantId": "8e1e397d-74c6-4f72-9735-7583dd199d48",
    "user": {
      "name": "donhuvy@hotmail.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  },
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "8e1e397d-74c6-4f72-9735-7583dd199d48",
    "id": "bacda0a9-17d5-480d-92e0-73fda3984a8f",
    "isDefault": false,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "vy-august2024",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantDefaultDomain": "donhuvyhotmail.onmicrosoft.com",
    "tenantDisplayName": "Default Directory",
    "tenantId": "8e1e397d-74c6-4f72-9735-7583dd199d48",
    "user": {
      "name": "donhuvy@hotmail.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  }
]
root@LT142:~#

in the same time, at web console



Why the results are different?

Can you explain more on your issue, what you are trying to do and what is your expected result you wanted and difference between expected and result you are getting?

I want the result at Azure CLI and Web console are the same. Why the different between Azure CLI and web console happen?

You mean to say you are not getting the fall2024sub in the list?

yes, It is one case. And 2 other stuffs has been deleted cb1c2d2d-685c-4da7-a032-e50920819397, but still shows on Azure CLI with State: true.

did you try login again using az login before?

When was your subscriptions got disabled?

issue could be a sync issue with the data. try re-login in Azure using az login.

did you try login again using az login before? Yes. When was your subscriptions got disabled? I tried after 10 minutes, 30 minutes, 2 hours, but Azure CLI results still did not reflect reality.

Try az account list --refresh

It works! Please post your answer, I will accept it.


az account list return different result with Web console:

az account list return different result values with Web console might be due to below reasons.

It could be due to the cache issue where the current console retrieves all the stored old information. This can lead to output the different result values. To resolve it, run az account clear and login again to list out the same values in both the console and portal.



Note: Once you have executed the cache clear command, reauthenticate with az login to perform and list out the operations.
And you can also use --refresh argument along with az account list to refresh the list of accounts under a specific tenant directory.
Refer this blog for the relevant issue.
az account list --refresh

Alternatively, you can check if there are any restrictions given for the specific accounts to not list out with the current user account.
